# Windows backup VS Volume snapshot

Tags: windows-server-2008, backup, amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

I have an EBS volume mounted as secondary volume on an EC2 .

I want  to back up data on the C drive (WEB application user document attachements ) of the EC2 instance :

1) Run a regular windows server  backups of the  C drive content (some data) and these backup are to be stored on the EBS volume

```
                        OR
```

2) Relocated the data subject to backup on the EBS volume and using AWS EC2 feature take a regular snapshot of the data .

Note that the web application has the feature where a user can attach some documents tied to his account . And i have in my app.properties file an option to change the location of the user attachements .

Do you know which one is better than the other (a part from the cost )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By regular Windows Server Backups, do you mean the backup utility or shadow copies? These are two very different things as Windows Backup backs up things to an image, shadow copies backs up incremental data as is, no image, you have to manually retrieve it.

Either way, doing both for double redundancy couldn't hurt. Some PCI compliance regulations require that.

Comment: Regular automated backups where you specify the drive on which you want the backup. Then this drive gets formatted and gets hidden by the system . When you want to retrieve data you go on the restore option on windows server to restore your data .